# PDF files made using inkscape does not show everything when opened in windows

Tags: pdf, inkscape

I made a small vector graphic using Inkscape, converted it to pdf. Then I opened the pdf in windows for printing purposes. Many of the lines and curves I made in Inkscape were missing.

Then I tried the same graphics in coreldraw. Converted it to pdf. Then I opened the file in Ubuntu. All lines and curves were there.

I want to use Ubuntu for all my work. But this problem makes it difficult for me as I have to take the pdf to a printer who works only with Windows.

Comment: Which PDF viewers are you using when you "open" the pdf?

Comment: I could see such a problem with the built in PDF viewer of IE10 on browserstack (probably an acrobat reader).

Comment: I solved this in Inkscape by selecting the path missing on Windows and by applying "Union" ... but I've no idea *why* this helped.

Answer (score 1):

Rest assured that you absolutely can use Inkscape in a professional graphics workflow - now to fix your issues...

There are a load of potential explanations for your observations. Can you upload the .svg file so we can take a look?

Martin is right to question what pdf viewer you're using. I've had files rendered with glitches by Evince but the files have viewed and printed fine elsewhere.

A top reason would be the stroke style for the affected lines - are they dashed or using end markers? I've had issues with these not outputting reliably in the past.

I'd also try opening the .svg file in [Scribus](http://scribus.net/canvas/Scribus) and outputting to pdf from there.  You've got more output settings, can handle bleed and add printers' marks etc.  Scribus opens svg files natively or you can 'Import Vector' into an existing Scribus document.

This is the version of Scribus I use to produce my print-ready artwork:

[image: Install via the software center]

or command line:

```
sudo apt-get install scribus-ng
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with some objects that had a blank stroke style. Removing their stroke completely made them appear again in the output PDF when viewed with Evince.

Answer (score 0):

None of this solved the issue for me (removing all strokes, using union). Half of my resume (a pdf generated from svg file with inskape) is disappearing when zooming over 150% with Evince. Only some part of the text appears and rasterized images disappears, there must be some underlying logic to this bug but I can't find it.

Scribus is unable to open my svg correctly, most of the file is missing.

However, I managed to get a working file by opening the svg in Gravit Designer and exporting it to a 300dpi pdf. Gravit does not like images in svg that much so I had to tweak them a little after the svg import. It is a workaround but at least it works, the pdf file is even light (400ko against 800ko with inkscape).

Answer (score 0):

When you go to print:

File - Print - (NOTICE THE RENDERING TAB AT TOP OF PRINT WINDOW)

Rendering - Select BITMAP

This works for me when some objects do not print - for example, clipped bitmaps.