# How to preserve italic font when exporting Inkscape SVG to EPS on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, fonts, inkscape, svg, eps

On Ubuntu 20.04, whenever I export an Inkscape (1.2) SVG drawing containing italic text to EPS, the result contains only straight text. I've tried exporting with "Embed fonts" selected, and with "Convert text to paths", but that doesn't make a difference.

Doing the same on MacOS 11.6.7 or Windows works just fine, so this seems to be an Ubuntu/Linux issue.

I've seen similar questions, like [Inkscape to PDF Font issue when saving/Exporting to PDF](https://askubuntu.com/q/631872/1646198) and https://stackoverflow.com/q/52554211/13727210, but haven't yet found an answer that works for me.

My current workaround is to export my SVG to PNG first, and then convert this PNG to EPS, but I'd appreciate a more straightforward solution. Any ideas?

EDIT: I asked this same question on the Inkscape forum. There, someone with Inkscape 1.2 on Linux Mint let me know that he didn't experience this issue.

UPDATE: A few days ago I upgraded to Ububtu 22.04 and re-installed Inkscape (it's one of the packages that was removed during the upgrade). After that, my italic sans-serif fonts turned out upright even in Inkscape itself; the option 'Italic' is still there in this Font style dropdown menu, but it just doesn't do anything (bold font still worked, though). Only when I changed all my text to FreeSans I was able to type italic text again. The good thing is that italic text in FreeSans correctly exports to EPS, so I'll use FreeSans instead of sans-serif from now on.

Comment: I doubt that the Ubuntu OS is the source of the issue. It is most likely an issue with the Ubuntu version of the app. You may want to explore it from that point of view.

Comment: @David, thanks for that. What exactly do you mean by "the Ubuntu version of the app"?

Comment: The version that runs on Ubuntu as opposed to the Mac or Windows version.

Comment: Ah, right, sorry. Hm, dunno, they're all version 1.2. Would the 1.2 Ubuntu version differ in any way from the 1.2 macOS/Windows versions, you think?

Comment: Yes I very much think they might.

Comment: Thanks, I'll ask the people at Inkscape so